# Prove this discrete mathematics problem true or false

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

Prove or disprove the following:

$$n\in \mathbb Z \; \text {is odd} \iff 8\; |\; (n^2 - 1)$$

I believe there are $2$ things to prove, but I am really lost. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Do you believe that the claim is true?

Comment: Going to the left is easy, since it $n^2-1$ is odd for n even. Going to the right is a straightforward induction proof.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $8\mid (n^2-1)$; in particular $n^2-1$ is even, so $n^2$ is odd.

Suppose $n=2k+1$ is odd; then
$$
n^2-1=4k^2+4k+1-1=4k(k+1)
$$
Can you tell why $4k(k+1)$ is divisible by $8$?

Comment: Because any real integer plugged into k is an even number greater than 8?

Comment: @theGrandWizod Not really. Since a factor $4$ is already there, you need to find another factor $2$ among $k$ and $k+1$: can you?

Comment: No I can not, Im lost sorry  :(

Comment: Can $k$ and $k+1$ both be odd?

Comment: @theGrandWizod If $k$ is even, done; if $k$ is odd then $k+1$ is…

Comment: @egreg k+1 is also even if k is odd

Comment: @egreg is that all there is too this?

Comment: @theGrandWizod Yes.

Comment: @egreg wow i feel dumb, thanks alot for your help!